# Can someone help me edit the code for limiting image dimensions

Tags: php

Can someone help me to edit the code. The code seems to be working, but there is a problem, when I add a new plugin in wordpress, it  prompts error. This code alert/error should only be in media library, but it also seems to affect the plugin page (admin). Thankyou

```
<?php 
/* Marc Dingena Utilities
 * Test image resolution before image crunch
 */
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter','mdu_validate_image_size');
function mdu_validate_image_size( $file ) {
    $image = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    $minimum = array(
        'width' => '400',
        'height' => '400'
    );
    $maximum = array(
        'width' => '2000',
        'height' => '2000'
    );
    $image_width = $image[0];
    $image_height = $image[1];

    $too_small = "Image dimensions are too small. Minimum size is {$minimum['width']} by {$minimum['height']} pixels. Uploaded image is $image_width by $image_height pixels.";
    $too_large = "Image dimensions are too large. Maximum size is {$maximum['width']} by {$maximum['height']} pixels. Uploaded image is $image_width by $image_height pixels.";

    if ( $image_width < $minimum['width'] || $image_height < $minimum['height'] ) {
        // add in the field 'error' of the $file array the message 
        $file['error'] = $too_small; 
        return $file;
    }
    elseif ( $image_width > $maximum['width'] || $image_height > $maximum['height'] ) {
        //add in the field 'error' of the $file array the message
        $file['error'] = $too_large; 
        return $file;
    }
    else
        return $file;
}
?>
```

---

Is my code correct?

```
function mdu_validate_image_size( $file ) {
    $image = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    if(@!is_array(getimagesize($image))){
     $image = true;
    }
    else {
    $image = false;
    }

    $minimum = array(
        'width' => '250',
        'height' => '180'
    );
    $maximum = array(
        'width' => '250',
        'height' => '180'
    );
    $image_width = $image[0];
    $image_height = $image[1];

    $too_small = "Image dimensions are too small. Minimum size is {$minimum['width']} by {$minimum['height']} pixels. Uploaded image is $image_width by $image_height pixels.";
    $too_large = "Image dimensions are too large. Maximum size is {$maximum['width']} by {$maximum['height']} pixels. Uploaded image is $image_width by $image_height pixels.";

    if ( $image_width < $minimum['width'] || $image_height < $minimum['height'] ) {
        // add in the field 'error' of the $file array the message 
        $file['error'] = $too_small; 
        return $file;
    }
    elseif ( $image_width > $maximum['width'] || $image_height > $maximum['height'] ) {
        //add in the field 'error' of the $file array the message
        $file['error'] = $too_large; 
        return $file;
    }
    else
        return $file;
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: the error is that when i wanted to upload new plugin, it gives me the message, i wanted to limit this only in media library

Comment: can you also help me in my otther question? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194747/help-in-editing-the-code-image-dimension-image-file-size-and-image-type

Answer (score 0):

Add new plugin maybe considered as uploading file.
Check if the file uploaded is an image or not before handling

```
if(@!is_array(getimagesize($mediapath))){
    $image = true;
} 
else {
    $image = false;
}
```

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408125/php-check-if-file-is-an-image
So, modify your code to

```
function mdu_validate_image_size( $file ) {
   $image = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
   if(@!is_array(getimagesize($image))){//check if file is an image
     //do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: hi thankyou, good karma for u n godbless :)

Comment: @pryde1919 if this answer worked for you please upvote and accept - karma isn't a currency here :)

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what he says.

Comment: I mean thankyou, I'm glad to have someone who is helpful and I wish for many good karma for you because you help me. Godbless.  and currency is no problem, if he has a donation tab, no doubt that I'll donated, because he is helpful. Donation and requesting money is different. People who help without requesting any return can have good karma, rather than requesting money which can easily spend.

Comment: @pryde1919 Please read [what should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) :-)